# Merging an array based on key and adding their values. Javascript/Es6/React

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, foreach

There are just 2 objects in an array where I need your attention at. I'm trying to find a way to merge these two objects into a single object based on `item.Symbol` and then add the values of their corresponding `item.TotalCost`, `item.Price`, and `item.Quantity` to the new object.

I tried doing a `Set` function but they just merge into 1 object and the values aren't added. I'm receiving an object like this:

```
[{
    CompanyName: "Microsoft Corp."
    Date: 1606503905
    Price: 215.23
    Quantity: 50
    Symbol: "MSFT"
    TotalCost: 10761.5
  },
  {
    CompanyName: "Microsoft Corp."
    Date: 1606503913
    Price: 215.23
    Quantity: 25
    Symbol: "MSFT"
    TotalCost: 5380.75
  }
]
```

Here is my code so far:

```
let set = new Set()
    const newSet = Objects.filter(item => {
        if (!set.has(item.Symbol)) {
            set.add(item.Symbol)
            return true;
        }
        return false},set
    )

console.log(newArray)
```

Note that the `Objects` variable contains the array of objects shown in the first code block.The set function I wrote only merges them into a single object based on their `Symbol` but I don't know where to go from here. I'm praying to the Javascript Overlords and Es6 Sith Lords to heed my call. May the force be with you.

Comment: could you also add the 'expected' output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the array of objects to an object, using the `Symbol` property as the key. If the key doesn't exist on the object, assign a clone of the current item to the key. If it exists, add the current item's values to the existing object:

```js
const arr = [{"CompanyName":"Microsoft Corp.","Date":1606503905,"Price":215.23,"Quantity":50,"Symbol":"MSFT","TotalCost":10761.5},{"CompanyName":"Microsoft Corp.","Date":1606503913,"Price":215.23,"Quantity":25,"Symbol":"MSFT","TotalCost":5380.75}]

const newArray = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
    if(!acc[o.Symbol]) acc[o.Symbol] = { ...o }
    else {
      acc[o.Symbol].Price += o.Price
      acc[o.Symbol].Quantity += o.Quantity
      acc[o.Symbol].TotalCost += o.TotalCost
    }
  
    return acc
  }, {})
);

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Here's an image of the [code snippet](https://imgur.com/a/UoKorJV). It would work but after  I get the 'total' object, I'd need to separate some values to be able to input it into the graph. I'm currently getting undefined at console.log. I'd really appreciate if you took a look at it. I just need someone to point me to the right direction.
master Ori Driori Kenobi.

Comment: You are using `newArray.TotalCost`, which is `undefined`, since `newArray` is an array. If you want the first object use `newArray[0]` or desturcture it.